# Stack Overflow and Segmentationfault in C on x86-32

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, callstack

i have a question regarding a stack overflow in C.
I wrote a little testing program, so when i start it with 8 As, i get what i expect, i write over the borders of the second buf and therefor buf1 is empty, because the trailing zero is first element in buf1 now.
So far so good, if i try it with 16 As it also works, event with 17 As. But i would expect a segfault here ... the segfault comes up after 24 As. Why is that? I tested on x86-32 ubuntu, debian and suse. Always segfault after 24 Byte...
On an AMD64 System with same code i get segfault after 32 As, just as i expected it ...
But why on x86-32 after 24????

## include

```
  #include <string.h>

  /*
  * $ gcc -O0 -Wall -fno-stack-protector buffer.c -o buffer
  *
  * $ ./buffer AAAAAAAA
  * buf1: test
  * buf2: test
  * buf1:
  * buf2: AAAAAAAA
  *
  * $ ./buffer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  * buf1: test
  * buf2: test
  * buf1: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  * buf2: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  * Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  */

  static void exploit(const char *InputString)
  {
char buf1[8];
char buf2[8];

strcpy(buf1, "test");
strcpy(buf2, "test");

printf("buf1: %s\n", buf1);
printf("buf2: %s\n", buf2);

strcpy(buf2, InputString);

printf("buf1: %s\n", buf1);
printf("buf2: %s\n", buf2);
  }


  int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
  {
if (argc > 1)
  exploit(argv[1]);

return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I think it is a good thing to be curious about this sort of thing, but you're invoking undefined behavior, and any segfault you do or do not get is implementation defined.

Comment: Hm just trying to understand behaviour of stack. compiled with -fno-stack-protector to see what happens. thought after overwriting buf1 i would directly overwrite the return adress with the trailing zero. but as i said on three different systems not after 16 byte but always after 24 .. Dont understand whats on the stack after the two bufs. maybe sfp and ret adress ... the segmentationfault will come, if i overrite the return adress of the function right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to guess the memory layout generated by the compiler. The compiler is free to layout the code in any way it seems fit. However, the stack frame must contain:

- The arguments (pushed by the caller)
- The return address (pushed by the CPU)
- The registers that need to be preserved. This is dependent on the target architecture.
- The local variables (allocated by the callee)

There are eight bytes between the local variables and the return address on the x86 machines you tested and sixteen bytes on the x64 machines. If the registers are saved by the callee, they are going to be stored in this space:

```
func:
PUSH BP
MOV BP, SP
SUB SP, privateSpace
...
MOV SP, BP
POP BP
RET argSize
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#x86

So, the space right after the return address contains the stored frame pointer BP. This overwrite will be unnoticed if the caller never uses the base pointer again. A function uses its base pointer to return, but if the function exits through a system call (I remember the main method being "special" in this sense, but I cannot source my claim), the corrupted base pointer is never used and the corruption will go unnoticed).

To test if it is the base pointer:

- Create a third level of calling (main, caller, callee).
- Log the return from callee, access a local variable, log again, and return.
- If the segfault occurs when accessing the local variable, it was most likely the base pointer.

Other possible causes:

- some debugging information that gets used if an error occurs.
- a canary (stack protector) that is never tested but it is allocated anyways. No symptoms whatsoever.
- number of arguments ([syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#syscall)) Corrupting this corrupts the caller's stack pointer, which will go unnoticed if the caller does not make another call. Symptom: segfaults in the caller if the caller makes a second call.
- the `this` pointer. Should not be present for ordinary functions.

Other things to try:

Make a memory dump in the callee before and after the corruption to see the layout. The stored base pointer should point to the stack space (caller's stack frame). The return address should point to the code space (near the current IP). The char* argument is a pointer. Flanking it with two other arguments (">>>" and "<<<" as `char[4]`) will help recognition.

Comment: ok i started my program in gdb and disassembled main and the function. but i am not sure about the output. but its too long to post it here :( http://pastebin.com/2hyUyWCC

Comment: The disassembly shows that the compiled code uses the standard entry routine. The `leave` instruction is equivalent to the `mov` and `pop` in the epilogue above. By memory dump I meant the stack frame, but the disassembly is useful as well. I will look into the code.

Comment: Can't tell why, but it seems to me the bytes -0x8(%ebp) through -0x1(%ebp) are indeed unused.

Comment: I particularly like the way the compiler handles the clean-up. Instead of pushing and popping, it writes below the stack pointer and does not need to clean up at all.

Comment: so i indeed have 8 "free" bytes before i begin to overwrite the return adress and change the return adress?

Comment: Actually, you are not overwriting the return address, but rather the caller's frame pointer, but the end result is the same - a crash. Also, I have no way to guarantee the one free word will always be present or unused.